# What is the most efficient way of retrieving data from a DataReader?

Tags: c#, performance, sqldatareader, data-access

I spend a lot of time querying a database and then building collections of objects from the query. For performance I tend to use a Datareader and the code looks something like:

```
while(rdr.Read()){
    var myObj = new myObj();

    myObj.Id = Int32.Parse(rdr["Id"].ToString();

    //more populating of myObj from rdr

    myObj.Created = (DateTime)rdr["Created"];
}
```

For objects like `DateTime` I simply cast the rdr value to the required class, but this can't be done for value types like `int` hence the (IMHO) laborious `ToString()` followed by `Int.Parse(...)`

Of course there is an alternative:

```
myObj.Id = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("Id"));
```

which looks cleaner and doesn't involve a call to `ToString()`.

A colleague and I were discussing this today - he suggests that accessing `rdr` twice in the above code might be less efficient that doing it my old skool way - could anyone confirm or deny this and suggest which of the above is the `best` way of doing this sort of thing? I would especially welcome answers from @JonSkeet ;-)

Comment: DateTime is also a value type, just like int. You do need to watch out for DbNull values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there will be a very appreciable performance difference, but you can avoid the name lookup on every row simply by lifting it out of the loop. This is probably the best you'll be able to achieve:

```
int idIdx = rdr.GetOrdinal("Id");
int createdIdx = rdr.GetOrdinal("Created");

while(rdr.Read())
{
    var myObj = new myObj();

    myObj.Id = rdr.GetFieldValue<int>(idIdx);

    //more populating of myObj from rdr

    myObj.Created = rdr.GetFieldValue<DateTime>(createdIdx);
}
```

Comment: That looks great, I've never looked at GetFieldValue<T> before, thanks very much indeed :-D

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, an alternative to the above is to wrap the IDataReader in a DbEnumerator.  DbEnumerator isn't well know and is mainly intended for databinding support, but it caches field name lookup in a Hashtable and provides similar performance improvement to the above for large result sets while keeping the code cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is are differences in performance in how you use `SqlDataReader`, but they are somewhere else. Namely the [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method accepts the `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`:

> Provides a way for the DataReader to handle rows that contain columns with large binary values. Rather than loading the entire row, SequentialAccess enables the DataReader to load data as a stream. You can then use the GetBytes or GetChars method to specify a byte location to start the read operation, and a limited buffer size for the data being returned.
>   When you specify SequentialAccess, you are required to read from the columns in the order they are returned, although you are not required to read each column. Once you have read past a location in the returned stream of data, data at or before that location can no longer be read from the DataReader. When using the OleDbDataReader, you can reread the current column value until reading past it. When using the SqlDataReader, you can read a column value only once.

If you do *not* use large binary values then it makes very little difference. Getting a string and parsing is suboptimal, true, is better to get the value with [`rdr.SqlInt32(column)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than a `GetInt32()` because of [`NULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlint32.isnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But the difference should not be noticeable on most application, unles your app is trully doing *nothing else* but read huge datasets. Most apps do not behave that way. Focusing on optimising the databse call itself(ie. have the query execute fast) will reap far greater benefits 99.9999% of the times.

Answer (score 2):

I usually introduce a `RecordSet` class for this purpose:

```
public class MyObjRecordSet
{
    private readonly IDataReader InnerDataReader;
    private readonly int OrdinalId;
    private readonly int OrdinalCreated;

    public MyObjRecordSet(IDataReader dataReader)
    {
        this.InnerDataReader = dataReader;
        this.OrdinalId = dataReader.GetOrdinal("Id");
        this.OrdinalCreated = dataReader.GetOrdinal("Created");
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.InnerDataReader.GetInt32(this.OrdinalId);
        }
    }

    public DateTime Created
    {
        get
        {
            return this.InnerDataReader.GetDateTime(this.OrdinalCreated);
        }
    }

    public MyObj ToObject()
    {
        return new MyObj
        {
            Id = this.Id,
            Created = this.Created
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<MyObj> ReadAll(IDataReader dataReader)
    {
        MyObjRecordSet recordSet = new MyObjRecordSet(dataReader);
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            yield return recordSet.ToObject();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
List<MyObj> myObjects = MyObjRecordSet.ReadAll(rdr).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice! Consider it *stolen* ;-)

Comment: Haha, that's okay. I switched to the entity framework, which does this sort of stuff automagically.

Comment: Would you recommend EF for smaller web-apps? I looked at it a few years back and it seemed heavy for the sort of day-to-day apps I build ...

Comment: MSDN has an extensive article regarding performance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327(v=vs.110).aspx

But if you want my opinion, I'd say learn how to use EF and never look back.

Comment: Perhaps a bit easier to read (but horribly outdated): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/03/27/ado-net-entity-framework-performance-comparison.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. I spend my life tweaking my hand-rolled and primitive proto-ORM :-(

Answer (score 1):

This makes the most sense to a reader. Whether it's the most "efficient" (you're literally calling two functions instead of one, it's not going to be as significant as casting, then calling a function). Ideally you should go with the option that looks more readable if it doesn't hurt your performance.

```
var ordinal = rdr.GetOrdinal("Id");
var id = rdr.GetInt32(ordinal);
myObj.Id = id;
```

Answer (score 1):

> For objects like DateTime I simply cast the rdr value to the required class, but this can't be done for value types like int

This isn't true: DateTime is also a value type and both of the following work in the same way, provided the field is of the expected type and is not null:

```
myObj.Id = (int) rdr["Id"];
myObj.Created = (DateTime)rdr["Created"];
```

If it's not working for you, perhaps the field you're reading is NULL?  Or not of the required type, in which case you need to cast twice.  E.g. for a SQL NUMERIC field, you might need:

```
myObj.Id = (int) (decimal) rdr["Id"];
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. The field I was casting is the primary key in the table I'm retrieving so I know there were no `NULL` values involved. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @5arx, put in a debugger breakpoint, and examine rdr["Id"].GetType().  If the SQL field is numeric, it will be decimal; if it's BIGINT, it will be long.  You have to cast it to the correct type first.

Comment: thanks I'll give it a go and report back - intriguing. Having said all that and returning to my original question, double casting appears to be a large step in the wrong direction - or is it?

Comment: @5arx, "double casting appears to be a large step in the wrong direction" - alternatives would be (a) declare your properties with the same type as the database, or (b) CAST/CONVERT in the SQL statement - e.g. "SELECT CAST(Id AS INT) Id, Created FROM ..."